# Gitlab CI build failed with "Preparation failed: cannot connect to Docker endpoint"

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

here is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```
image: maven:3-jdk-8
build:
   script: "mvn install -B"
```

then the build will failed with below error

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.8.0 (734bc5d)
Using Docker executor with image maven:3-jdk-8 ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: cannot connect to Docker endpoint
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image maven:3-jdk-8 ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: cannot connect to Docker endpoint
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image maven:3-jdk-8 ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: cannot connect to Docker endpoint
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Build failed (system failure): cannot connect to Docker endpoint
```

this is how to start the runner

```
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
  gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

this is how to config the runner

```
docker exec -it gitlab-runner gitlab-runner register

Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com )
https://gitlab.com
Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner
xxx
Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner
my-runner
INFO[0034] fcf5c619 Registering runner... succeeded
Please enter the executor: shell, docker, docker-ssh, ssh?
docker
Please enter the Docker image (eg. ruby:2.1):
maven:3-jdk-8
INFO[0037] Runner registered successfully. Feel free to start it, but if it's running already the config should be automatically reloaded!
```

is there anything else I just missing above?

Comment: There isn't enough information here. How is your runner configured? Is the docker daemon running?

Comment: @Frap thanks for your attention, I just updated my question with the information you mentioned above

Comment: @YuwenYan did you find a solution?